# How to remove an element from a HashMap with multiple keys in JAVA

Tags: java, dictionary, oop, hashmap

In my system an element from a HashMap have multiple keys, like an element "chess" have the keys "board", "game", "strategy". I want to remove the element chess and every key pointing to him.

For example, thats the map: `private Map<String, Artigo> listaArtigos = new HashMap<String, Artigo>();`

The Artigo a1 have the keys "nasa", "space", "mars". I need to delete a1 and all his keys, cuz i think that every time i set an new map ("nasa", a1), it creates a new a1 with a new key, right? Like in this case i have 3 a1's in my map?

Comment: This sounds like a misunderstanding of how `Map` works. Firstly, `Map` stores references to objects, it doesn't control creation (outside of semantics like `#compute`). Secondly, a `Map` stores a single value _per key_, which can be referenced by the key you store it with (primarily through `#get(Key)` and `#put(Key, Value)`). Consider if you truly want a map in this case (you typically wouldn't keep multiple keys for one value, but it's not _always_ bad). Lastly, what are you truly attempting to achieve by using this `Map`?

Comment: @Rogue i want to set individual keywords for articles

Comment: What if a keyword applies to more than one article? It may be better to have `Artigo` (what I assume is `Article`) store a `Set<String>` of the keywords that are relevant to it.

Comment: You should make a data structure using classes instead. Some of these classes could contain maps. Let your data structure have specific methods for your different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<String, Artigo> listaArtigos = new HashMap<String, Artigo>();

//for your example from above
listaArtigos.remove("nasa", a1);
```